# Loading Facebook data into a table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am stuck on the PROPER way to get all a user's Facebook friends and load it into a table view (I would simply use FBFriendPickerViewController but its ugly and it doesn't appear that you can fix that)

All I want is the profile picture in the cell imageView and name in the cell textLabel, simple as that.

Doing it with NSURL/NSData doesn't crop the images, Id much rather use FBProfilePictureView so please try to use that in any solutions. Thanks!

Get data from Facebook

```
-(void)facebookOpenSession {

    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [[FBRequest requestForMyFriends] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

            if (error) {
                // handle error
            } else {
                self.facebookFriends = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[result objectForKey:@"data"]];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"facebookRequestForMyFriends" object:self];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Configure data into cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *friend = [self.facebookFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = friend.name;

    NSURL *profilePictureUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=normal", friend.id]];

    NSData *profilePictureData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:profilePictureUrl];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:profilePictureData];

    return cell;
}
```

How do people learn how to make all these things with the Facebook SDK, I spent almost 4 hours trying to do what I described above and I feel like I am completely missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several open source libraries that make the task of downloading an image easy. My favorite is [AFNetworking](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html), but there's also [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). Using one of these categories, your task becomes as simple as:

```
[myImageView setImageURL:"http://test.com/test.jpg"];
```

Even if you don't want to use these libraries, don't do it the way you're currently attempting it (i.e. `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:profilePictureUrl]`). I believe that is a synchronous operation that will block your UI. Use code from one of the 2 links above, or make your own UIImageView category.